# Horizontal scrollbar has appeared on my Activity tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-accounts

I have just noticed that on my activity tab a horizontal scrollbar appears at the bottom of the page (not in picture) and the `all` tab appears to be cut off.

[image: Activity Overflow]

Tested in Chrome 8.0 & FF 3.6.8.  IE7 is even more bizarre and has both scroll bars. I'm not too bothered about that though as I don't use IE.

This doesn't happen for SO or MSO just seems to be on WebApps

Comment: I'm looking into this now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fix will be in the next deployment.

Comment: I'm seeing this on Gaming and Programmers' at the moment.

Comment: @Jin - This bug is still happening?

Comment: @Barry I just pushed another fix in. I'll double check after the next deployment.

Comment: @ChrisF I also put in a fix for Gaming and Programmers as well.

Comment: It seems to be fixed, but the Votes, Tags and Badges headings now appear to be sort of centred.

Comment: @ChrisF My last fix introduced some new bugs as you mentioned. I have put a new fix on dev, should be live in the next deployment.

Comment: OK - though I did notice the scroll bar on Webmasters ;)

Answer (score 1):

I see it too. CSS bug? A missed width or overflow setting, perhaps?

Can someone ping Jin to have a look?